# Story about an ecological dystopia where the world has no more birds

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a story I read for 9th grade English back in 1984. It's an ecological dystopia that tells of a world with no more birds. A boy thinks he sees a real bird. He wades in the water and it's an old statue that he pushes.